# How to convert an Image to Icon?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need convert the image that is in `String` or `Byte` to Icon to show in ToolbarItems.
I need show the photo from user in right side from menu of the app.

My code until now:

```
this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("name", "icon", () =>
{
}, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
```

If i set an icon from project, him show me like this:

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what errors you receive.

Comment: @AMartinNo1 I don't receive errors, i have only the property with the image filled with whats recorded in the DB

Comment: @AMartinNo1 In this point, i need convert this return to can show in the ToolbarItems. Or do you have other idea, please ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `ToolbarItem` in Xamarin.Forms can only use local files (app resources).

See the [API documenation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem.Icon) - the property is a `FileImageSource`, which can only take a local file path.